# Sharing link and image if Facebook native app is not installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I am using Facebook Android SDK 4.6 in my application. I don't have Facebook native app installed on my device. The Facebook docs mentioned that the ShareDialog.show() will fallback to web dialog in case native Facebook app is not installed. I shared link (ShareLinkContent) using ShareDialog from my main activity (MainActivity.java) and it is working fine. 
Now, sharing a link from another activity (WebViewActivity.java) always shows error message (Error. Please try later) inside the dialog. I have verified the link share using ShareApi.share() and it is working fine. 
Please tell why ShareDialog is not working in WebViewActivity.java ?
 **NOTE:**
I have successfully logged in with publish_permissions using LoginManager from the MainActivity.java. I have a button in MainActivity.java to share and it is working fine. But another button in WebViewActivity.java always show error inside the dialog. 
Also, sharing the bitmap using SharePhotoContent model could not be achieved using ShareDialog. I have to use ShareApi.share(). 
Is there no way to show ShareDialog for the image sharing ?
Attaching the dialog error image here:
[image: Facebook ShareDialog error]

Comment: The web share dialog does not support image uploads, so sharing of images can only be done via the API or native app. Can you post some code from your WebViewActivity around how you're doing the share?

Comment: @johnrao07 I used ShareApi for my purpose.

Comment: I tried that...but it does nothing....does it display a dialog before posting...?Can you post the solution,it'll help me and others too...there isn't any good answer for this issue...!